# User systematically deleting and re-posting questions

Tags: support, status-completed, deleted-questions, abuse

There are users asking questions, deletes and re-asks them if he doesn't get an answer, and also deletes them as soon as he gets a satisfactory one.

Examples for solved questions he deleted (I called upon Chat.Meta to undelete so they may be active again):

- [Xml add element node using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640707/xml-add-element-node-using-php) ([revision list](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4640707/revisions))
- [Load select option values from XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611169/load-select-option-values-from-xml-file) ([revision list](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4611169/revisions))
- [Removing entire element based on text value PHP XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638839/removing-entire-element-based-on-text-value-php-xml) ([revision list](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4638839/revisions))
- [Simple variable question in PHP and XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632441/simple-variable-question-in-php-and-xml)

Examples for deleted and re-posted questions from Google (I'm not searching through them all) in which he is being warned about re-posting questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641125/replace-element-value-in-xml-php ([revision list](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4641125/revisions))
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637601/delete-entire-element-based-on-text-value
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637262/php-xml-help-me-correcting-and-completing-my-code
- [PHP XML add edit delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635799/php-xml-add-edit-delete)

[Full Google listing](http://www.google.com/#q=user560411+site:stackoverflow.com&hl=en&&safe=off&prmd=ivns&source=lnt&tbs=qdr:w&sa=X&ei=JA4qTbLrGI7EswbO1N23Ag&ved=0CA4QpwU&fp=76a11da8afbb7d99)

This guy needs some kind of permanent boot.

> **Update**: The guy came back to ask [another useless XML question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642030/display-xml-using-php), and delete all  the undeleted content again (except for those parts that  were protected in the meantime by upvotes) , despite numerous comments and links to this Meta question. He is clearly not interested in changing his behaviour.

Comment: There should be a new limit on SE: 'You may only delete one question per week.' This limit should replace the awful 'Wait ten minutes before marking this answer as accepted'-limit.

Comment: I agree that it is unacceptable, but please do not lower yourself to his level and mind your language.

Comment: @Gamecat, wait I'll edit it. I just hate that limit >.<

Comment: @Gamecat I can accept criticism about my language, but what do you mean by me lowering myself to his level? Because of the call to undelete? (I didn't see anything wrong with that but I'm open to arguments)

Comment: @Time never mind, I edited it

Comment: @Pekka I think Gamecat was talking to me. :)

Comment: @Time ah, I overlooked that, all right :) In that case, I'm rolling back the edit I made to the question :D

Comment: @Pekka, I mean the language, you can perfectly make your point without using these words. I hate it when great people lower themself to cope with trollish behaviour.

Comment: @Gamecat I sometimes *need* to use foul language when something angers me :) But you're right of course.

Comment: And I know, sometimes the actions of people can make you mad as hell. The hardest part is to keep yourself up to level. So sorry if I sounded a bit offensive, I just tried to help (which sometimes can go terribly wrong.)

Comment: @Gamecat @Pekka I can't live without foul language! I use it all the freaking time. :D

Comment: @Pekka, we are both right. But foul language needs to be spoken (preferably loud).

Comment: @Gamecat re your 2nd last comment: No offense taken. I *will* use the occasional swear word, but I have no problem removing them or having them edited out. Re your last comment: fair point :)

Comment: Thanks. English is not my native language, and sometimes the message send does not cover the meaning. But learning all day keeps you awake (sometimes all night).

Comment: @Gamecat yeah, I know what you mean. Sometimes, it would be helpful to have video chat just to make sure something comes across the right way.

Comment: Most of the questions are undeleted now. Now out of undelete votes.

Comment: I undeleted the ones with answers and left him a comment to please stop this.  I'll check back to see what happens.

Comment: @Bill all right, cheers. Although I think this guy doesn't care... we shall see

Comment: @Bill he doesn't care after all. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642030/display-xml-using-php please please block him on IP level :)

Comment: @Pekka: Ah well, I had to give him the benefit of the doubt.  I'll have to see if a suspension gets his attention before I can escalate to an IP block.  Those are *exceedingly* rare.

Comment: @Bill yeah, of course! I just have an inkling that this particular user will need extreme measures. I'll be watching the XML tag more closely than usual for the next few days.

Comment: @Pekka: I have the same feeling.  But you can take 3 days off, then start watching it again.  ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Odd behavior - deleting question and creating it again?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116973/odd-behavior-deleting-question-and-creating-it-again)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think his/her account should be suspended for at least 3 days, and he/she should receive an email about what he/she has misdone.

If he/she continues, his/her delete-privilege should be dropped.

---

<sup>Yes, women can also be programmers.</sup>

Comment: At least a serious warning. (And I want more undelete votes ;-)

Comment: *his/her delete-privilege should be dropped* — wondering if that is an option?

Comment: @Arjan sure, this prevents him from deleting his own questions.

Comment: I meant: does the current system allow for that? I've only seen accounts fully suspended, not any partial privileges being taken away.

Comment: @Arjan I'm not sure, but I think this is easy to implement. I don't think it's a bad idea to implement this anyway.