# What happens when someone deletes his own Question/Answer?

Tags: support, self-delete

A user can delete his/her question/answer. My question is, is there any loss to the user by doing this? Are there any reputation changes by doing so? What are all consequences on deletion?

For example, when deleting an answer with zero votes is there any reputation change?

What if the user is an established user? In that case will the user get banned and have no change to reputation?

Comment: They may get banned if they delete too many, since it will considered as vandalism.

Comment: A similar question is http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74599/does-deleting-my-own-question-or-answer-attract-penalty

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Comment: @Mat Can you please answer my edits?

Comment: @nhahtdh, I don't think that, for the automatic ban, deleting many posts is considered vandalism. Instead I think it is considered as proof that the post was low quality, and hence wasted the reader's time and should not have been posted to start with.

Comment: ...please don't change your question like that. First of a all: one question per post please. Also, don't invalidated existing answers by just adding new questions to your post.

Comment: Reputation & possible ban are two completely different things. Reputation gained or lost from the post is removed when it is deleted, regardless of who the user is. The ban takes into account many factors, some of which might be related to poster's past activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No one really has defined exactly how many deletions it takes, but if you delete too many questions or answers, this is the potential consequence: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/182513)

In short, there is an automatic process that analyzes a number of criteria, one of which is the number of deletions and the result is you can be banned from asking more questions/answers until you raise you reputation enough to lift the ban.

But in response to your edit, a deletion will adjust your reputation accordingly (a negative score post will add the lost rep back, and a positive score post will removed the gained rep).  As such, a zero score post will not affect your score at all.  But regardless the potential for suspension or automatic ban is still there if you do it too much.

And for your second edit, my understanding is the question/answer ban will affect *anyone*, although for an established user with lots of rep and numerous questions/answers, due to the other criteria that is considered, it would take a significant amount of deletion to kick in (can't find a link to support this though).

And just to add some addition info, and a really great answer to a similar question, take a look at this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74637/182513) to the question FallenAngel linked in the comments.  I think that pretty much covers what I said and more.