# Odd behavior - deleting question and creating it again?

Tags: discussion, edits, moderation

I've experienced a couple of times now that a certain user has created a question and after a couple of criticizing - and reasonable - comments,   the question is removed by the author. A few days later the same question appears and the same thing happens again.

For a specific question this has happened several times. And my personal opinion is that this behavior undermines both the purpose of SO and the purpose of the ability to remove your own questions.

But what should be done - if anything at all - when this occur?

Comment: Eventually, this user [might get an automated ban](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86982/should-i-avoid-deleting-my-questions).

Comment: possible duplicate of [User systematically deleting and re-posting questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74459/user-systematically-deleting-and-re-posting-questions) (though that does not have a helpful answer like @Fabian's).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Flag for moderator attention and explain what you observed. You can't do anything about this as a regular user, but moderators can see the older deleted questions and take action.

Asking the same question multiple times is either a complete misunderstanding of how the SE sites work or outright abuse of the system. The users should be told what they are doing wrong, and suspended if they are not willing to stop this behaviour.