# Where do I report people for deleting their questions on purpose after they get an answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Today I was looking at the question of this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1031018/user1031018). The question was pretty simple, he was looking for the `eval` function in [php](/questions/tagged/php) not knowing of it's existence. He received a comment and while I was finishing reading the question, I saw him commenting

> Thanks, eval() is what I was looking for.

and then he deleted his question. In my opinion, such behavior isn't appropriate. So, should I just ignore this or can I do something about it?

Comment: First, true, that behavior is not appropriate, flag the user for Mod-Attention...second, that question isn't appropriate either.

Comment: Yeah, I'd just let it go.

Comment: A good starting point for the whole "what to do with rage quits/vandalism" family is this question: [What to do when the OP mutilates their own question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114803/what-to-do-when-the-op-mutilates-their-own-question?lq=1)

Comment: `flag the user for Mod-Attention` - I am unable to find such option in a user's profile :(

Comment: [Flag abusive users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/flag-abusive-users)

Comment: Also, be aware that deleting of (downvoted) questions will lead to the phenomenon of "The Mysterious Appearing Duplicates" of [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers). Also, no need to flag anything anymore, since you've come to Meta anyway (not the normal way).

Comment: Don't forget that a low reputation user who does this too often will be automatically question-banned.

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128618/155556

Comment: *"I am unable to find such option in a user's profile "* There is not option to flag a user...go to some item of their content, flag there and explain in the comment field.

Comment: Thank you for advice, everyone :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The user may generally be acting out of many possible motivations.

- Honest attempt to delete a subpar question
- Embarrassment of some kind
- Misunderstanding of the purpose of the site ("thanks, problem solved")
- Covering tracks (homework, interviews, contests, trade secrets)
- Annoyance at a comment or answer
- Vampire style of doing his job ([like](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74459/user-systematically-deleting-and-re-posting-questions?rq=1) [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471))

You have also multiple way to quash your mild frustration.

- Ignore the occasional incident
- Find their question in browser history, post it under your own name and self-answer it.
- Answer only questions by well known posters.
- Comment on another post by that person to ask them to undelete
- Use a free form flag (if you can't see the deleted question, flag another post by that person) for moderator attention to the person or question. Explain about the deleting.
- Fill some kind of a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135538/disallow-deletion-of-questions-for-24-hours-after-last-answer-was-posted) here at meta

There is probably not a single interpretation of this phenomenon.  It is relatively common to edit or delete own answers based on comments.  Sometimes, a comment in place of an answer is deliberately used to encourage some action on the part of the OP.  Comments are not intended to be long lived, although in more complex situations, some of them often end up to be.

Therefore, if there was no *answer* posted by the time the question got deleted, I would assume that the user has interpreted, and acted on, the *comment* in one of many available entirely appropriate ways.